# getting intermittent issue when building my angular 5 project

Tags: angular, typescript

when i build my ng5 project getting below errors intermittently

```
ERROR in .&#x2F;node_modules&#x2F;smart-lookup&#x2F;index.ts‌
Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for H:\..somepath...\node_modules\smart-lookup\index.ts.
You should not need to recompile .ts files in node_modules.
Please contact the package author to advise them to use --declaration --outDir.
```

i have searched for solutions and added

```
resolve: {
        extensions: [
          ".js", ".ts"
        ]},
```

but it didnt help.

my command to build ng5 project is

```
"webpack -p --config configs/webpackConfig/webpack.prod.js --progress --optimize-minimize --env=prod --colors && webpack --config configs/webpackConfig/webpack.dev.js --progress --optimize-minimize"
```

### my webpack.dv.js file is

```
var webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge");
var WriteFilePlugin = require("write-file-webpack-plugin");
var commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
var path = require("path");
const DynamicPublicPathPlugin = require("./dynamic-public-path-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig.get(), {
    entry:{
        "polyfills": path.resolve(__dirname, "../polyfills.ts")
    },
    output: {

        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../distribution/__buildversionFolder__/'),
        publicPath:"#_path#/#{buildVersion}_myproj/",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
          ".js", ".ts"
        ]},
    plugins: [        
        new WriteFilePlugin(),
        new DynamicPublicPathPlugin({
            externalGlobal: 'window.__cdnPath', //Your global variable name.
            chunkName: [] // Chunk name from "entry".
        })
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: "minimal"/*,
        TODO setup when REST service ready
        proxy: {
            "/api/**": {
                target: "http://localhost:8080/nurdbot-rest-service",
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }*/
    }
});
```

### my webpack.prod.js file is

```
var webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var WriteFilePlugin = require("write-file-webpack-plugin");
var commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
const DynamicPublicPathPlugin = require("./dynamic-public-path-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig.get(), {
    entry:{
        "polyfills": path.resolve(__dirname, "../polyfills.ts")
    },
    output: {       
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../distribution/__buildversionFolder__/'),        
        publicPath:"#_path#/#{buildVersion}_myproj/",
        // publicPath: "/",
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.min.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
          ".js", ".ts"
        ]},

    plugins: [
        //new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
        new WriteFilePlugin(),
        new DynamicPublicPathPlugin({
            externalGlobal: 'window.__cdnPath', //Your global variable name.
            chunkName: [] // Chunk name from "entry".
        }),        
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({            
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
                DEBUG:false

        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(
            {
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
                  }
            }
        ),

          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
           compress: { warnings: false },
           comments: false,
           mangle: false,
           minimize: false

        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: "minimal"/*,
        TODO setup when REST service ready
        proxy: {
            "/api/**": {
                target: "http://localhost:8080/nurdbot-rest-service",
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }*/
    }
});
```

it get builds on server but it causes issue whenever i make some change in my package.json file.

Comment: Did you try to exclude "node_modules" in the tsconfig.json file? `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`